# Can't Add Icon To Electron App With Electron Builder

Tags: electron, yarnpkg, electron-builder

I have made an app with Electron and am trying to package it with Electron Builder.

> Link to repository

Does not contain node_modules folder: [Repo here](https://github.com/Handmade-Studios/app-attendant)

I have a folder named build with my icon.ico in it and my package.json is as follows:

```
{
    "name": "attendant",
    "productName": "Attendant",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "description": "A simple app to streamline web development by allowing you index.html to open on a live server in the default browser",
    "main": "main.js",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "electron .",
        "pack": "electron-builder --dir",
        "dist": "electron-builder"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "electron": "^8.0.1",
        "electron-builder": "^22.3.2"
    },
    "build": {
        "appId": "com.attendant",
        "win": {
            "icon": "./build/icon.png",
            "title": "Attendant",
            "msi": true
        }
    }
}
```

However, I receive the following error:

```
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Any ideas why this happening and how to fix it?

With the following `package.json`:

```
{
    "name": "attendant",
    "productName": "Attendant",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "description": "A simple app to streamline web development by allowing you index.html to open on a live server in the default browser",
    "main": "main.js",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "electron .",
        "pack": "electron-builder --dir",
        "dist": "electron-builder build"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "electron": "^8.0.1",
        "electron-builder": "^22.3.2"
    },
    "build": {
        "appId": "com.attendant",
        "directories": {
            "buildResources": "build"
        },
        "win": {
            "icon": "build/icon.png",
            "title": "Attendant",
            "msi": true
        }
    }
}
```

I receive the error:

```
yarn dist
yarn run v1.22.0
warning package.json: No license field
$ electron-builder build
  • electron-builder  version=22.3.2 os=10.0.18363
  • loaded configuration  file=package.json ("build" field)
  • author is missed in the package.json  appPackageFile=C:\Users\alexr\Documents\GitHub\attendant-app\app\package.json
  ⨯ Invalid configuration object. electron-builder 22.3.2 has been initialised using a configuration object that 
does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.win should be one of these:
   object { additionalCertificateFile?, appId?, artifactName?, asar?, asarUnpack?, certificateFile?, certificatePassword?, certificateSha1?, certificateSubjectName?, compression?, cscKeyPassword?, cscLink?, detectUpdateChannel?, electronUpdaterCompatibility?, extraFiles?, extraResources?, fileAssociations?, files?, forceCodeSigning?, generateUpdatesFilesForAllChannels?, icon?, legalTrademarks?, protocols?, publish?, publisherName?, releaseInfo?, requestedExecutionLevel?, rfc3161TimeStampServer?, sign?, signAndEditExecutable?, signDlls?, signingHashAlgorithms?, target?, timeStampServer?, verifyUpdateCodeSignature? } | null
   -> Options related to how build Windows targets.
   Details:
    * configuration.win has an unknown property 'title'. These properties are valid:
      object { additionalCertificateFile?, appId?, artifactName?, asar?, asarUnpack?, certificateFile?, certificatePassword?, certificateSha1?, certificateSubjectName?, compression?, cscKeyPassword?, cscLink?, detectUpdateChannel?, electronUpdaterCompatibility?, extraFiles?, extraResources?, fileAssociations?, files?, forceCodeSigning?, 
generateUpdatesFilesForAllChannels?, icon?, legalTrademarks?, protocols?, publish?, publisherName?, releaseInfo?, requestedExecutionLevel?, rfc3161TimeStampServer?, sign?, signAndEditExecutable?, signDlls?, signingHashAlgorithms?, target?, timeStampServer?, verifyUpdateCodeSignature? }
    * configuration.win has an unknown property 'msi'. These properties are valid:
      object { additionalCertificateFile?, appId?, artifactName?, asar?, asarUnpack?, certificateFile?, certificatePassword?, certificateSha1?, certificateSubjectName?, compression?, cscKeyPassword?, cscLink?, detectUpdateChannel?, electronUpdaterCompatibility?, extraFiles?, extraResources?, fileAssociations?, files?, forceCodeSigning?, 
generateUpdatesFilesForAllChannels?, icon?, legalTrademarks?, protocols?, publish?, publisherName?, releaseInfo?, requestedExecutionLevel?, rfc3161TimeStampServer?, sign?, signAndEditExecutable?, signDlls?, signingHashAlgorithms?, target?, timeStampServer?, verifyUpdateCodeSignature? }
     How to fix:
     1. Open https://www.electron.build/configuration/win
     2. Search the option name on the page (or type in into Search to find across the docs).
       * Not found? The option was deprecated or not exists (check spelling).
       * Found? Check that the option in the appropriate place. e.g. "title" only in the "dmg", not in the root. 
  stackTrace=























                                                                   ValidationError: Invalid configuration object. electron-builder 22.3.2 has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.   























                                                                    - configuration.win should be one of these:  























                                                                      object { additionalCertificateFile?, appId?, artifactName?, asar?, asarUnpack?, certificateFile?, certificatePassword?, certificateSha1?, certificateSubjectName?, compression?, cscKeyPassword?, cscLink?, detectUpdateChannel?, electronUpdaterCompatibility?, extraFiles?, extraResources?, fileAssociations?, files?, forceCodeSigning?, generateUpdatesFilesForAllChannels?, icon?, legalTrademarks?, protocols?, publish?, publisherName?, releaseInfo?, requestedExecutionLevel?, rfc3161TimeStampServer?, sign?, signAndEditExecutable?, signDlls?, signingHashAlgorithms?, target?, timeStampServer?, verifyUpdateCodeSignature? } | null























                                                                      -> Options related to how build Windows targets.























                                                                      Details:























                                                                       * configuration.win has an unknown property 'title'. These properties are valid:























                                                                         object { additionalCertificateFile?, appId?, artifactName?, asar?, asarUnpack?, certificateFile?, certificatePassword?, certificateSha1?, certificateSubjectName?, compression?, cscKeyPassword?, cscLink?, detectUpdateChannel?, electronUpdaterCompatibility?, extraFiles?, extraResources?, fileAssociations?, files?, forceCodeSigning?, generateUpdatesFilesForAllChannels?, icon?, legalTrademarks?, protocols?, publish?, publisherName?, releaseInfo?, requestedExecutionLevel?, rfc3161TimeStampServer?, sign?, signAndEditExecutable?, signDlls?, signingHashAlgorithms?, target?, timeStampServer?, verifyUpdateCodeSignature? }























                                                                       * configuration.win has an unknown property 'msi'. These properties are valid:























                                                                         object { additionalCertificateFile?, appId?, artifactName?, asar?, asarUnpack?, certificateFile?, certificatePassword?, certificateSha1?, certificateSubjectName?, compression?, cscKeyPassword?, cscLink?, detectUpdateChannel?, electronUpdaterCompatibility?, extraFiles?, extraResources?, fileAssociations?, files?, forceCodeSigning?, generateUpdatesFilesForAllChannels?, icon?, legalTrademarks?, protocols?, publish?, publisherName?, releaseInfo?, requestedExecutionLevel?, rfc3161TimeStampServer?, sign?, signAndEditExecutable?, signDlls?, signingHashAlgorithms?, target?, timeStampServer?, verifyUpdateCodeSignature? }























                                                                        How to fix:























                                                                        1. Open https://www.electron.build/configuration/win























                                                                        2. Search the option name on the page (or type in into Search to find across the docs).























                                                                          * Not found? The option was deprecated 
or not exists (check spelling).























                                                                          * Found? Check that the option in the appropriate place. e.g. "title" only in the "dmg", not in the root.















































                                                                       at validate (C:\Users\alexr\Documents\GitHub\attendant-app\app\node_modules\@develar\schema-utils\dist\validate.js:50:11)























                                                                       at validateConfig (C:\Users\alexr\Documents\GitHub\attendant-app\app\node_modules\app-builder-lib\src\util\config.ts:229:3)























                                                                       at Packager._build (C:\Users\alexr\Documents\GitHub\attendant-app\app\node_modules\app-builder-lib\src\packager.ts:342:5)























                                                                       at Packager.build (C:\Users\alexr\Documents\GitHub\attendant-app\app\node_modules\app-builder-lib\src\packager.ts:337:12)























                                                                       at executeFinally (C:\Users\alexr\Documents\GitHub\attendant-app\app\node_modules\app-builder-lib\node_modules\builder-util\src\promise.ts:12:14)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

> ## Edit number 2

I am now receiving the following error:

```
yarn run v1.22.0
warning package.json: No license field
$ electron-builder build
  • electron-builder  version=22.3.2 os=10.0.18363
  • loaded configuration  file=package.json ("build" field)
  • author is missed in the package.json  appPackageFile=C:\Users\alexr\Documents\GitHub\attendant-app\app\package.json
  • writing effective config  file=dist\builder-effective-config.yaml
  • packaging       platform=win32 arch=x64 electron=8.0.1 appOutDir=dist\win-unpacked
  • asar usage is disabled — this is strongly not recommended  solution=enable asar and use asarUnpack to unpack 
files that must be externally available
  ⨯ cannot execute  cause=exit status 1
                    errorOut=Fatal error: Unable to commit changes

                    command='C:\Users\alexr\AppData\Local\electron-builder\Cache\winCodeSign\winCodeSign-2.5.0\rcedit-x64.exe' 'C:\Users\alexr\Documents\GitHub\attendant-app\app\dist\win-unpacked\Attendant.exe' --set-version-string FileDescription Attendant --set-version-string ProductName Attendant --set-version-string LegalCopyright 'Copyright © 2020 Attendant' --set-file-version 1.1.0 --set-product-version 1.1.0.0 --set-version-string InternalName Attendant --set-version-string OriginalFilename '' --set-icon 'C:\Users\alexr\Documents\GitHub\attendant-app\app\dist\.icon-ico\icon.ico'
                    workingDir=
  ⨯ C:\Users\alexr\Documents\GitHub\attendant-app\app\node_modules\app-builder-bin\win\x64\app-builder.exe exited with code ERR_ELECTRON_BUILDER_CANNOT_EXECUTE  stackTrace=

                                                  Error: C:\Users\alexr\Documents\GitHub\attendant-app\app\node_modules\app-builder-bin\win\x64\app-builder.exe exited with code ERR_ELECTRON_BUILDER_CANNOT_EXECUTE

                                                      at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\alexr\Documents\GitHub\attendant-app\app\node_modules\app-builder-lib\node_modules\builder-util\src\util.ts:239:14)

                                                      at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:313:26)

                                                      at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:223:5)

                                                      at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)

                                                      at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:283:5)

                                                  From previous event:

                                                      at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:439:21)

                                                  From previous event:

                                                      at WinPackager.signApp (C:\Users\alexr\Documents\GitHub\attendant-app\app\node_modules\app-builder-lib\src\winPackager.ts:357:27)

                                                      at WinPackager.doPack (C:\Users\alexr\Documents\GitHub\attendant-app\app\node_modules\app-builder-lib\src\platformPackager.ts:243:16)

                                                      at WinPackager.pack (C:\Users\alexr\Documents\GitHub\attendant-app\app\node_modules\app-builder-lib\src\platformPackager.ts:114:5)

                                                      at Packager.doBuild (C:\Users\alexr\Documents\GitHub\attendant-app\app\node_modules\app-builder-lib\src\packager.ts:444:9)

                                                      at executeFinally (C:\Users\alexr\Documents\GitHub\attendant-app\app\node_modules\app-builder-lib\node_modules\builder-util\src\promise.ts:12:14)

                                                      at Packager._build (C:\Users\alexr\Documents\GitHub\attendant-app\app\node_modules\app-builder-lib\src\packager.ts:373:31)

                                                      at Packager.build (C:\Users\alexr\Documents\GitHub\attendant-app\app\node_modules\app-builder-lib\src\packager.ts:337:12)

                                                      at executeFinally (C:\Users\alexr\Documents\GitHub\attendant-app\app\node_modules\app-builder-lib\node_modules\builder-util\src\promise.ts:12:14)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

thanks for the support so far

Comment: Do you need windows config alone or ? and I hope you no need the installer. Right?

Comment: Try the absolute path instead of relative path

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
"build":{
    "productName":"yourProductName",
    "appId":"org.yourProductName",
    "dmg":{
        "contents":[
            {
                "x":130,
                "y":220
            },
            {
                "x":410,
                "y":220,
                "type":"link",
                "path":"/Applications"
            }
        ]
    },
    "win":{
        "target":[
            "nsis",
            "msi"
        ]
    },
    "linux":{
        "target":[
            "deb",
            "rpm",
            "snap",
            "AppImage"
        ],
        "category":"Development"
    },
    "directories":{
        "buildResources":"resources",
        "output":"release"
    },
    "files: ["resources/**/*"], // including buildResources folder in order to use this in the code
        },"
```

I attached example electron-builder configuration that I configured for my project before.
Please consider this part

```
"directories": {
    "buildResources": "resources",
    "output": "release"
}
```

`buildResources` should include resource files like icons. If you are not going to set this `buildResources` manually then the default will be `build`.
`output` is indicating where the packaged app will be after packaging and it's optional for your issue. Anyhow, I've set the project to generate release artifacts on the "release" folder.

In this project, I'm saving the icons in the project root directory like below. I don't know where your icon files are so I've attached the project structure that is working with this build configuration.

[image]

Comment: thanks for the reply, I am now receiving the following error: `⨯ Application entry file "main.js" in the "C:\Users\alexr\Desktop\app-test\release\win-unpacked\resources\app.asar" does not exist. Seems like a wrong configuration.`

Comment: @Alex Hawking Please make sure if the main.js is existed at your root directory

Comment: You can see the "main":"main.js" at your package.json

Comment: This main should indicate the electron main.js

Comment: I have `"main": "main.js"` in my package.json and my main.js in the same directory as my yarn.lock (the main directory)

Comment: @AlexHawking do you have repo at github? Can I check your project structure? if you don't mind?

Comment: Yes sure I will upload it, it is currently local aha, thanks for your help so far

Comment: I have added link to repo in answer

Comment: @AlexHawking I created pull request and check that.

Comment: Or you can just copy the above build configuration to your package.json

Comment: I'm getting same error
⨯ Application entry file "main.js" in the "/Users/zestgeek1/Desktop/mng-agent/dist/mac/mng-agent.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar" does not exist. Seems like a wrong configuration.  stackTrace=

Comment: my folder structure is 
{
  my-project
     -dist
     -node_modules
     -release-builds
     -resources
     -index.html
     -main.js
     -package-lock.json
     -package.json
}

Comment: @tpikachu, Do you have any idea how we can change the tooltip of created windows desktop shortcut

Comment: I had my build folder within a subfolder `app`, setting `"directories": {"buildResources": "app/build"}` did the trick. I also included the path in `"files" : ["build/icon.ico","build/icons/*"]`

Answer (score 7):

I Just went through your logs, I found the below error,

`configuration.win has an unknown property 'title'. These properties are valid:`

The title of the app should be given in `productName` property. The `title` keyword is invalid according to the [document](https://www.electron.build/configuration/win).

Also, I figured out there is `buildResources` that is missing in the build configurations. I recommend using `.ico` file for icons instead of `png` images.

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "electron .",
    "pack": "electron-builder --dir",
    "dist": "electron-builder build"
},
"build": {
    "productName": "Attendant",
    "appId": "com.experiment.attendant",
    "directories": {
        "buildResources": "build"
    },
    "files": [
      "build/**/*",
    ],
    "win": {
        "asar": false,
        "target": "nsis",
        "icon": "build/icon.ico"
    },
    "nsis": {
      "installerIcon": "build/icon.ico",
      "installerHeaderIcon": "build/icon.ico",
      "deleteAppDataOnUninstall": true
    },
}
```

For more configurations,

1. [Common Configurations](https://www.electron.build/configuration/configuration)
2. [Windows Configurations](https://www.electron.build/configuration/win)

See the working example for windows and Linux configurations.
[GITHUB](https://github.com/gokulakannant/text-to-speech/blob/master/package.json)

Comment: @AlexHawking The given error logs are not enough. Add full crash logs, that maybe help us to find the issue.

Comment: I am running `yarn dist`

Comment: @AlexHawking, Can you edit your question with full terminal logs?

Comment: @AlexHawking, I have updated the answer based upon the edited question.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion and now receiving an error as updated in my question, also thanks for your help so far

Comment: @AlexHawking, The icon file should be in `.ico` format.

[Refer the link](https://www.electron.build/configuration/configuration#overridable-per-platform-options) under `fileAssociations`.

Comment: Convert the .png file to .ico file and make sure the file is present in the build folder. Also, I have edited the answer accordingly

Comment: @AlexHawking, https://github.com/gokulakannant/text-to-speech. 

This is my working experimental project on electronjs. Here the all windows and linux configurations are working. You can go through the package.json build configurations